# Installing PyMOL from source code

Tags: compiling, pymol

I've tried running:

```
prefix=/opt/pymol-svn
modules=$prefix/modules

python setup.py build install \
    --home=$prefix \
    --install-lib=$modules \
    --install-scripts=$prefix
```

with the following output (with several lines before it):

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp: In function ‘void* VLADeleteRaw(void*, int, unsigned int)’:
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp:364:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if(index < -old_size)
                   ^
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp:376:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
        (index < vla->size) && ((count + index) <= vla->size)) {
                      ^
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp: In function ‘void* VLAInsertRaw(void*, int, unsigned int)’:
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp:397:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
       if(index < -old_size)
                   ^
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp:404:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if(index > old_size)
                ^
layer0/MemoryDebug.cpp:407:49: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if((index >= 0) && (count > 0) && (index <= old_size)) {
                                                 ^
ov/src/OVLexicon.cpp: In function ‘OVreturn_word OVLexicon_BorrowFromCString(OVLexicon*, const ov_char8*)’:
ov/src/OVLexicon.cpp:348:11: warning: variable ‘cur_index’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   ov_word cur_index = 0;
           ^
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c layer0/Word.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/layer0/Word.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c layer0/Map.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/layer0/Map.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/OVHeap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/OVHeap.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/ov_utility.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/ov_utility.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/OVHeapArray.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/OVHeapArray.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from layer0/os_python.h:33,
                 from layer0/Matrix.cpp:16:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from layer0/os_python.h:33,
                 from layer0/Word.cpp:18:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from layer0/os_python.h:33,
                 from layer0/Map.cpp:17:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/OVRandom.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/OVRandom.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from layer1/Ortho.h:28:0,
                 from layer0/Matrix.cpp:24:
layer0/os_gl.h:32:20: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include<GL/glew.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from layer1/View.h:21:0,
                 from layer1/PyMOLObject.h:28,
                 from layer0/Word.cpp:26:
layer0/os_gl.h:32:20: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include<GL/glew.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/OVContext.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/OVContext.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c layer1/Setting.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/layer1/Setting.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
ov/src/OVContext.cpp: In function ‘void OVContext_Del(OVContext*)’:
ov/src/OVContext.cpp:21:13: warning: variable ‘heap’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     OVHeap *heap = I->heap;
             ^
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_PYMOL_LIBPNG -D_PYMOL_INLINE -D_PYMOL_OPENGL_SHADERS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -D_PYMOL_CGO_DRAWBUFFERS -D_PYMOL_GL_CALLLISTS -D_PYMOL_VMD_PLUGINS -D_HAVE_LIBXML -D_PYMOL_FREETYPE -DNO_MMLIBS -D_CGO_DRAWARRAYS -DOPENGL_ES_2 -D_PYMOL_NUMPY -Iov/src -Ilayer0 -Ilayer1 -Ilayer2 -Ilayer3 -Ilayer4 -Ilayer5 -Imodules/cealign/src -Ibuild/generated -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/include -Icontrib/uiuc/plugins/molfile_plugin/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ov/src/OVOneToOne.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/ov/src/OVOneToOne.o -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-empty-body -Wno-char-subscripts -ffast-math -funroll-loops -O3 -fcommon
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from layer0/os_python.h:33,
                 from layer1/Setting.cpp:17:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
fusion809@fusion809-Vostro-3500:~/Downloads/pymol$ In file included from layer1/Ortho.h:28:0,
                 from layer1/Setting.cpp:27:
layer0/os_gl.h:32:20: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include<GL/glew.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

If you suggest I use the software centre/apt-get to install it well it's not an option as the version in the software centre is a little old (1.7.0) when the latest edition is 1.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end of that log:

```
layer0/os_gl.h:32:20: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include<GL/glew.h>
```

So try installing [`libglew-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=GL%2Fglew.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any):

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
```

Comment: This gives several lines of output, but no installation. These are the last few lines: `layer1/CGO.cpp:4641:91: warning: ‘org_colorVals’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*total_vert*4, org_colorVals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

Comment: @BrentonHorne Skip the warnings and look for errors.

Comment: I found one 'fatal error', namely: `libxml/xmlwriter.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>`

Comment: @BrentonHorne That would be [`libxml2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libxml%2Fxmlwriter.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).